# Splitting Values in new column in rapidminer 5

Tags: rapidminer

In rapidminer 5 I would like to split values of a column and put the new values in a new column. I.e:

BIC|"Cognome"|"Nome"|"Via_completa"|"Civico"|"Esponente"|"CAP"|"Frazione"|"Comune"|"Provincia"
50417273|"ACCROCIA"|"ALESSANDRO"|"VIA NAPOLI"|"66"||"00100"||"MILANO"|"MI"

The "Via_completa"column is made out of the values 'VIA' and 'NAPOLI'. To normalize the address according to my data set I would like to split the values 'VIA' and 'NAPOLI' in the column "Via_completa", create a new column called 'DUG' and place value 'VIA' in the new column.
Like this:

BIC|"Cognome"|"Nome"|"DUG"|"Via_completa"|"Civico"|"Esponente"|"CAP"|"Frazione"|"Comune"|"Provincia"
50417273|"ACCROCIA"|"ALESSANDRO"|"VIA"|"NAPOLI"|"66"||"00100"||"MILANO"|"MI"

In Excel there is a 'text into columns' function. Is there an operator in Rapid miner to execute this function?
Thanks,
Friso

Answer (score 0):

The `Split` operator is one option. You need to supply a regular expression to the `split pattern` parameter of this operator. For a space `\s+` should suffice. This outputs new attributes with names based on the original attribute but with `_1, _2, ...` appended so you might need to do some renaming afterwards.